# JPA 2 under Geronimo with Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, geronimo

I have Spring MVC App integrated with Hibernate. Everything was OK until I use @OneToMany annotation... I'm  getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1912)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:805)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:745)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 81 more
```

Here's my WEB-INF/lib contents:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
h2-1.3.164.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar
spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
tiles-template-2.2.2.jar
```

I saw that for some people helped ejb3-persitence.jar removing but my classpath doesn't contain that jar.
There's everythinh OK if I run this app under other application servers like JBoss or Glassfish.

Comment: Post the code for your `OneToMany` relation.

Comment: Geronimo must have JPA 1.0 classes in one of its own jar files, and these classes are loaded instead of the JPA 2.0 ones in your WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but how I can fix this? I thought that WEB-INF/lib libraries have higher priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class is provided in several jar files so you need to ensure that your application is using the correct one.

First you need to workout which one it is using. Try and remove it from your WEB-INF/lib folder and if you still get the same error then it means it is loaded from somewhere else.

Also try and copy it to $TOMCAT_HOME/lib as a test to see what happens.

If you are using Eclipse try and verify the JRE/JDK you are using because the javaee-api-5 also includes these classes. It might also be worth ensuring that the javaee-api is not being included when it is loaded by Tomcat.

Examples of jar files to that can cause conflicts with your hibernate-jpa jar file is given below (could have different version numbers):

```
 persistence.jar
 toplink-essentials.jar
 ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar
 ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
 ejb3-persistence-3.3.2.Beta1.jar
 geronimo-jpa_1.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
 geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.0.jar
 geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
 geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.jar
 persistence-api-1.0.jar
 geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0-PFD2.jar
 geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.0-M1.jar
 glassfish-persistence-api-b32g.jar
 javaee-api-5.0-1.jar
 javaee-api-5.0-2.jar
 openjpa-all-2.0.0-M3.jar
 openejb-itests-standalone-client-3.0.1.jar
 openejb-itests-standalone-client-3.0.jar
 openejb-itests-standalone-client-3.1.1.jar
 openejb-itests-standalone-client-3.1.jar
```

The issue is definitely caused by conflicts with the jar files you just need to try different situations to work out exactly where the conflict is.

Comment: Actually, I've found problematic library.  `/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_1.0_spec/1.1.2/geronimo-jpa_1.0_spec-1.1.2.jar`. As you can see library isn't compatibile with JPA 2. It seems that there's no rational solution better than Geronimo upgrade

Comment: I found workaround for that problem with Geronimo (Jetty). The solution is the same for Geronimo with Tomcat. Here's the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9642172/420652)

Comment: Good. Hopefully somebody else will also find this useful.